# wordpress url rewrite alpha numerical pagination

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a aplhanumeric pagination and wanting to have pretty url

On Page `http://www.mysite.com/glossary/`

0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | [A](http://www.mysite.com/a) | B | C | [D](http://www.mysite.com/d) | E | [F](http://www.mysite.com/f) | [G](http://www.mysite.com/4) | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z

```
Apple
Alicia
Amy
A sweet Candy
.
.
.
.
and so on
```

current url on aplha numeric has a `http://www.mysite.com/glossary/?list=a`
 and I want to have url with this

```
http://www.mysite.com/a
http://www.mysite.com/b
http://www.mysite.com/c
and so on.. .
```

any idea on how to code this in `.htacess` url rewrite to achieve that url?

update

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/mysite/([^/\.]+)/?$ glossary/?list==$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /glossary/?list=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi @Gundars I tried the code but it doesnt seems to work I have update my question with my current .htacess

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: always the most complex to the less complex rule.

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mysite/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]{1})$ glossary/?list=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

If it doesn't work try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mysite/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-z]{1})$ glossary/?list=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot my rule of thumb. updated my answer. hope this works

Comment: it doesnt work too I try to visit http://www.mysite.com/a if can this like glossary/a much be better I think do you know how do this one thanks